# NSNumber to NSString (without trailing zeros if it has decimals)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsnumber

I'm struggling with this issue, and I couldn't find any resource for it :
I have an `NSNumber` that I want to display in an `UITextField`, so the user can edit it.
So I need to convert this `NSNumber` to an `NSString`, like this :

```
float value  -> desired string value
1.0000000... -> 1
10.000000... -> 10
1.1230000... -> 1.123 or 1,123 depending on the locale
1000000.0... -> 1000000
```

I've tried to use `NSNumberFormatter`, but then I get spaces or comas for big numbers :

```
1000000.0... -> 1,000,000 or 1 000 000 depending on the locale
```

I also tried

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", val]
```

But then for big numbers I have a scientific expression :

```
1000000.0 -> 1e+06
```

Did somebody have a successful experience with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSNumberFormatter` has such method as :

```
- (void)setGroupingSeparator:(NSString *)string
```

I think, you can return to variant where you has:

```
1000000.0... -> 1,000,000 or 1 000 000 depending on the locale
```

and set additional parameter using that function:

```
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@""];
```

Or moreover try this method:

```
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this option. It works for the US local, I'll make some tests with other locales, and accept your answer if it works :-)

Answer (score 3):

`NSNumberFormatter` **is** the solution, you were on the right path.

But:

- the formatting it uses depends on the locale (either it uses the default locale if you don't override it, or you can set the locale used by the NSFormatter), because the `NSLocale` information also carries the Region Formatting info (formatting numbers using the US locale or the FR locale leads to different formats and different representations)
- You can customize the formatting by tuning the options of `NSNumberFormatter`, like changing the grouping separators used, changing the decimal separator, etc.

This way you can really customize the way the `NSNumberFormatter` represents the numeric value into a string.

Answer (score -2):

try converting nsnumber value to NSInteger or CGFloat and store it in the new variables. Then set the converted variables to uitextfield.

```
CGFloat floatNumber = [numberInNSNumber floatValue];

textfield.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",floatNumber];
```

I think it should work for you..!!

Comment: `floatValue` doesn't necessarily return a `CGFloat`, and anyway, unboxing the number into an `NSInteger`, a `CGFloat`, or some other kind of value does not solve the problem of converting the value to and from a string.